# Как получить имя файла для его дальнейшего использования

Tags: android, изображения, файлы

Как получить имя файла (изображение), для его дальнейшего использования. Изображения в `assets`

Comment: так они же и так все известны, просто бери по имени файла

Comment: типа string_array.get(n)?

Answer (score 4):

Для этого вы можете использовать [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) для получения `InputStream` посредством вызова его метода `open()`. Остается только преобразовать поток (декодировать) используя метод `decodeStream()` класса [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) для получения `Bitmap`.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Далее можно использовать полученый Bitmap, например вот так:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_myImageView);
Bitmap bitmap =  getBitmapFromAsset(assetName);
iv.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
```

Почитать про [setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользовать недокументированной фичой с доступом через URI типа:

```
file:///android_asset/my_image.png
```

Но более правильный способ изложен у [@jimpanzer](/users/11957/jimpanzer)

Comment: Почему же недокументированной? Просто хорошо спрятано http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)

Comment: Пожалуй, слишком хорошо спрятано... К тому же это не документация, а ссылка на недокументированную возможность :)